# Thunderbird 52.9.1 (64-bit) fails to connect to server on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, email-client

Since yesterday, I have got a problem on Thunderbird that fails to connect to servers (imap servers) (both gmail and not-gmail types).

I have tried to uninstall thunderbird via Ubuntu Software and reinstalling it by `sudo apt --reinstall install thunderbird`, but after rebooting nothing really has changed.

Regarding security settings, connection security is SSL/TLS and authentication method is OAuth2.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently solved by removing thunderbird and its related hidden directory .thunderbird located at home. Then reinstalled thunderbird.

I am not sure this is the final and best solution, but, at least for now, is a solution.